# Make Sheets Enter Row Number into a Designated Cell

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, if I write "Jeff" in a cell on Row "X", how do I get "X" (row number where I wrote "Jeff") to be entered into a cell on row "Jeff" on another sheet.

Sorry if this is a weird request, I have some experience with Excel Macros but I can't figure this out

The Sheet with the yellow highlight is what I want to manually enter, the Sheet with the blue highlight is what I want the code to make for me

Input:

[image: [Manual Entry](https://imgur.com/8hEjK3C)]

Result:

[image: [Wanted Result](https://imgur.com/mgCoacy)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you get a list of names with rows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 "♠"&B1:E&"♦"&ROW(A1:A)),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey this is great! Thank you so much!